# Do Chrome extension V3 `service_workers` run in parellel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm migrating a Chrome extension from manifest version 2 to version 3.

I see that `background` scripts must be placed under the new `service_worker` object.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#man-sw

It seems from the documentation I can specify multiple `service_worker`.  Do these script run in parallel?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation suggests that?..

Comment: `...` in the example means "the rest of manifest.json", not a repetition of the declaration. BTW, there's an [upcoming change in the documentation's source repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/pull/3693) that clarifies some of the articles to reinforce the notion that there's just one SW. See if it clarifies this article as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one service worker. I know it's not clear about that, but we are working on fixing the documentation.

Incidentally, if you need multiple files you can [load ES6 modules into your service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#man-sw:%7E:text=Even%20though%20Manifest%20V3%2C%20does%20not%20support%20multiple%20background%20scripts%2C%20you%20can%20optionally%20declare%20the%20service%20worker%20as%20an%20ES%20Module%20by%20specifying%20%22type%22%3A%20%22module%22%2C%20which%20allows%20you%20to%20import%20further%20code.). I would give you more guidance, but I'm new on this product and have not had a chance to even try this myself.